# Was there incarnation of Satya and Treta yugas personified in Mahabharata or in any other scripture?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavata-purana

We know that Kali who is the ruler of Kali yuga incarnated as Duryodhana and Dwapara incarnated as Shakuni.

But what of the other two yugas of Sathya and Treta.

Who rules these yugas? Were they incarnated during Mahabharata ? If yes, then as whom did they incarnate? Apart from Mahabharata did this personification mentioned in some other texts ?

Comment: Why is madhvacharya a tag for this question?

Comment: @GIRIBLR because he wrote a detailed commentary on Mahabharata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question,I would like to bring to your notice the fact that in the **Puranas** ,Satya Yuga  is shown as a person who actually fights(under the command of Lord Vishnu as Kalki) against Kali.

Here is one quotation from Kalki Puran that describes a pre War conversation between Lord Kalki and Satya Yuga:

(Kalki Puran,Chapter 19)

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Text 4 and 17 will answer your question:

The incarnation of Satya Yuga is by name **Maskari**

Comment: great!.. i think only Text 4, 17 are enough..as of now the answer is unnecessarily big..